# Spring Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring, post

i'm currently studying about spring, and i'm making a very basic app. I just want to make a button that makes a post and redirect me to another page. If i return a simple String, the app works fine, but if i try to return a html page, the app don't work anymore... I'm running some tests, and he works with GET methods, but why he doesn't works with POST ?
Thx, and sorry for english.

Here's my code:

```
@Controller
public class CompraMaça {

@RequestMapping(value = "/maca", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String maca() {

    return "maca.html";
  }
}
```

the button.html:

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <form action="/maca" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="Compre uma maçã" style="display:block">
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and the page i want to return:
maca.html

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Parabéns !</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Você comprou uma maçãzona !</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: in chrome network tab i get this:

```
General:
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/maca
Request Method:POST
Status Code:405 
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade 



 Response Headers:

Allow:GET, HEAD
Content-Language:en-US
Content-Length:338
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 19 Mar 2018 17:23:39 GMT


Request Headers

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: On `action` attribute try to set the entire address, like: http://www.myapp.com.br/maca

Comment: i've just tried it,but without success. Thx

Comment: What is your viewResolver?

Comment: I don't have. Is it necessary in this case ?

Comment: If you see any warnings/errors related to InternalResourceViewResolver in log then that's the reason. Basically when you say "maca.html" Spring needs to resolve it into a file URL.

Comment: the only error i get is:
2018-03-19 14:19:28.160  WARN 12059 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: Ok, then perhaps the controller class isn't being scanned by Spring for annotations. You might need to use `@ComponentScan` or `context:component-scan` (XML) and provide your controller's package name.

Comment: i think some where in your code you have setViewResolver("jsp") if so try to change extension of your maca.html to maca.jsp and remove extension from your method return "maca";

Answer (score 0):

the code worked with:

```
return "redirect:/maca.html";
```

Someone knows why ?
Thx